# Check if a string array has same string value or not using Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, lambda

I have an extensions array and I have to find out whether all the elements in the array has the same value or different values using lambda expressions. I have written the below code and its always returning me **true**. In the following extensions array, it should return me **false** as the .bmp is different extensions than others. Could you help me to achieve the task?

```
  string[] extensions = { ".doc", ".doc", ".bmp" };
  var result = extensions.All(x => extensions.Contains(x));
```

Comment: You could use `.Distinct()` and check the length. If it is 1, all are the same, and if it is >1, you have different values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are checking if all items in an array are contained in this array, which is of course true.

You want:

```
string firstExt = extensions.First();
var allSame = extensions.Skip(1).All(x => firstExt == x); // use String.Equals(s1,s2,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) if you want to compare in a case insensitive manner
```

Other way using `Distinct` (not more efficient):

```
var allSame = !extensions.Distinct().Skip(1).Any();
```

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen: even better than source or IL is [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) because if it's mentioned there it won't change in future implementations and you can rely on it: _"The enumeration of source is stopped as soon as the result can be determined."_

Answer (score 0):

Case-sensitive comparison:

```
string[] extensions = { ".doc", ".doc", ".bmp" };
bool hasSameExtensions = extensions.Distinct().Count() == 1;
```

Case-insensitive comparison:

```
string[] extensions = { ".doc", ".doc", ".DOC" };
bool hasSameExtensions = extensions.Distinct(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).Count() == 1;
```